# Next.js assetPrefix breaks less loader

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new to Next.js. Any help will be appreciated.

The app works fine in local dev environment. However, as soon as I add the following to `next.config.js`, next.js thorw an error.

```
// next.config.js
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

module.exports = {
  // Use the CDN in production and localhost for development.
  assetPrefix: isProd ? 'https://cdn.mydomain.com' : '/example',
}
```

```
#### error message
error - ./styles/fonts.less 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> @font-face {
```

Not sure what the issue is. Any help is welcomed. The following is all the config I have with my app.

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages();

const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS({
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    url: false
  }
})

const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less')

/* With CSS Modules */
module.exports = withLess({
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    sourceMap: true,
    localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
    localsConvention: 'camelCase',
    camelCase: 'dashes',
  }
})


const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

module.exports = {
  // Use the CDN in production and localhost for development.
  assetPrefix: isProd ? 'https://cdn.mydomain.com' : '/example',
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the root cause of the my problem. Multiple `module.exports` caused the issue since the last one will override all previous ones. It means there will be no loader to deal Less/CSS. I also decided to use `next-compose-plugins` plugin to help me deal with multiple plugins. Otherwise, I have to do something like `withCSS(withLESS())`.

```
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less');

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [withLess, {
      cssModules: true,
      cssLoaderOptions: {
        sourceMap: true,
        localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        localsConvention: 'camelCase',
        camelCase: 'dashes',
      }
    }],
    [withCSS],
    [withImages],
  ],
  {
    /* global config here ... */
    assetPrefix: isProd ? 'https://cdn.cloudfront.net/vpassets' : ''
  },
);
```